# Bloquear en datepicker bootstrap intervalo de fechas desde BD

Tags: javascript, laravel

tengo un daterangepicker el cual recibe fechas del backend, para bloquear dichas fechas en el datepicker.
He estado leyendo la documentación de moment.js, y su respectivo método `isBetween`, y también el plugin de `range`, ademas de algunos ejemplos que he visto. Ya que me he dado cuenta de que solo puedo añadir fechas sueltas para bloquearlas, lo cual es estupendo, pero me quedan muchos días que deberían estar bloqueados, con lo cual aun no es funcional.
He intentado modificar el método para utilizarlo pero la verdad no se muy bien como hacerlo ya que no me arroja errores, simplemente no funciona.

El código de javascript que tengo hecho hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
  // here receive the json array from PHP to JS


 var daysData = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
  var isArea = {{ Auth::user()->area_id }}
  var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA[m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = j;
  }
}
console.log(daysData);
$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

isInvalidDate: function(date) {
    var valid = false ; // default css class
    let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
        if(newA[d].area_id !== isArea){
            if(newA[d].acept == 1){
                valid =  true;
            }
        }
    }
    return valid;
},
isCustomDate: function(date) {

  var daySettings = 'day_green';
  let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
       daySettings = 'day_red';
       if(newA[d].area_id == isArea){
           if(newA[d].acept == 0){
            daySettings = 'day_orange';
           }
        }
  }
  return daySettings;
},
```

EDITADO
y el json que recibo en el array despues del bucle en la vista es este:

```
[17/08/2018: {…}, 18/08/2018: {…}, 22/08/2018: {…}, 23/08/2018: {…}, 
24/08/2018: {…}, …]
09/08/2018:
acept:0 
area_id: null
end: "2018-08-10"
start: "2018-08-09"
title:"asd"
__proto__:Object
10/08/2018:{area_id: null, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-09", end: "2018-08- 
10", acept: 0}
17/08/2018:{area_id: 1, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-17", end: "2018-08- 
18", acept: 1}
18/08/2018:{area_id: 1, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-18", end: "2018-08- 
22", acept: 1}
22/08/2018:{area_id: 1, title: "asdf", start: "2018-08-22", end: "2018-08- 
24", acept: 1}
23/08/2018:{area_id: 1, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-22", end: "2018-08- 
23", acept: 1}
24/08/2018:{area_id: 1, title: "asdf", start: "2018-08-22", end: "2018-08- 
24", acept: 1}
length:0
__proto__:Array(0)
```

pero realmente no me lo está haciendo, y he visto que el método isBetween, no me sirve exactamente para lo que yo quiero hacer. Y creo que no estoy codificandolo como deberia.

Muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso creo que lo mas fácil es justo cuando te llegue el *JSON*  es crearte un array con todas las fechas que **no** queremos mostrar.

Si partimos de un json tal:

```
var daysData= [{
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Comida",
    "start": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
    "end": "2018-08-15 00:00:00",

}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Conferencia",
    "start": "2018-08-19 00:00:00",
    "end": "2018-08-22 00:00:00",
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2018-08-27 00:00:00",
    "end": "2018-08-29 00:00:00",
},
 {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2018-09-27 00:00:00",
    "end": "2018-09-29 00:00:00",
}];
```

Entonces, cuando nos llegue nos guardamos los que no queremos mostrar en `newA`:

```
var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA.push(m.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    }
}
```

El `for` que hay dentro utilizara como bucle los dias entre `start` y `end`. Y `m` sera una 1 dia mas, asi hasta que llegue a 'end'.

Entonces `newA` es un Array con todas las fechas que no queremos mostrar:

```
newA = [
  "13/08/2018",
  "14/08/2018",
  "15/08/2018",
  "19/08/2018",
  "20/08/2018",
  "21/08/2018",
  "22/08/2018",
  "27/08/2018",
  "28/08/2018",
  "29/08/2018",
  "27/09/2018",
  "28/09/2018",
  "29/09/2018"
]
```

Ahora que tenemos todos los dias que no queremos mostrar, en la funciones solamente tenemos que saber si existe o no este 'date' dentro de esta array con indexOf:

```
isInvalidDate: function(date) { 

      var valid = false; 
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");    
      if(newA.indexOf(d) !== -1){ //se comprueba la posicion
        valid = true;
      }
      return valid;
    },
isCustomDate: function(date) { 

      var daySettings = 'day_green';
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      if(newA.indexOf(d) !== -1){
        dayData = newA[d]
        daySettings = 'day_red';
      }
      return daySettings;

    },
```

---

Tienes el ejemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/9g1u3er5/)

---

**EDITO:**

YA que necesitas que cambie de color (la clase) dependiendo de un campo interno en el JSON, el array tiene que cambiar.

El tema esta en que también tiene que llegar el `accept` a la función:

```
var newA = [];
for( j of jsonT){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA[m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = j;
    }
}
```

Entonces, lo que vamos hacer es multiplicar el array por todos los días que no quieres mostrar. Siendo el dia la clave del array.

Entonces en la función solamente necesitas comprobar si existe o no la variable con `typeof`

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

    isInvalidDate: function(date) { 
      var valid = false ; // default css class
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
        valid =  true;
      }
      return valid;
    },
   isCustomDate: function(date) { 

      var daySettings = 'day_green';
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
       if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
       daySettings = 'day_red';
        if(newA[d].accept == 1){ //Aqui compruebas accep
           daySettings = 'day_orange';
        }

      }
      return daySettings;

    },
});
```

Tienes el ejemplo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/9g1u3er5/12/)

Comment: Esto es como lo haria yo, creo es mas sencillo prepararte un la informacion antes de hacer nada y luego solo comprobaciones

Comment: Muuuuchisimas gracias a la primera y funcionando!. Mas o menos es la manera en la que suelo trabajar, no me gusta trabajar sin saber que me llega, luego vienen las sorpresas jeje. Solo me queda una pequeña duda para hacer un pequeño filtro, he añadido un campo que es aceptado, que puede ser 1 o 0, en función de si es 1 o 0 quiero que se pinte de rojo o naranja todo el intervalo de fechas que cojemos, con lo cual, mi pregunta es,(aunque creo que ya la has respondido), con el indexOf me valdría para saber que dato contiene ese aceptado?

Comment: Entiendo, entonces, yo lo que haria seria cambiar el array. dejame que lo prueve el fiddle

Comment: el array ahora mismo tiene estos atributos: 10/08/2018:{area_id: null, title: "asd", start: "2018-08-09", end: "2018-08- 
10", acept: 0}    esta todo completamente funcional, pero he metido ese campo para intentar hacer ese filtro, y que si no esta aceptado me lo pinte en otro color distinto para dejarlo como una posible eleccion.. no se si me explico muy bien, creo que se como hacerlo, solo me falta como saber que tiene ese campo de ese array

Comment: Te lo he editado para lo de las clases. Vaya parrafo tu

Comment: Lo siento.... ':d ahora lo miro, muchas gracias.

Comment: nonono, que vaya rallada te estoy metiendo en la respuesta solo por que he cambiado un `for` y un `if`

Comment: Se entiende genial, y mira que nobato como soy con javascript, para que yo lo entienda, de aqui a profe :D Muchas gracias en serio, funcional y perfecto.

Comment: Buenas @Txema, queria realizarte una consulta por no abrir un hilo nuevo para una modificacion de esto, voy a editar el codigo para que veas los cambios que realize, pero intento realizar que en el datepicker solo me muestre las fechas (bloqueadas o no) para el mismo area_id que el usuario logueado, te lo intento explicar mejor arriba. Gracias por tu atención y disculpa las molestias..

Comment: hola @DavidPazóLópez, ya lo veo, podrias hacer un `console.log(isArea, typeof isArea, newA[d].area_id, typeof newA[d].area_id )` por que no veo problema ninguno salvo que la comparacion no funcione.

Comment: quizas cambiando `!==` por `!=`. o que el `isArea` sea `true` y no 1 o algo por el estilo y que no este entrando bien en el if

Comment: He probado justamente de hacer console.log de newA[d].area_id y no me imprime ningun valor, sin embargo en el array si que estan los datos. Probare a hacer los cambios a ver si lo consigo

Comment: Nada, he probado como me dices y sigue igual, ni filtra ni leches, voy a intentar hacer el filtro en el php para solo mandarle los datos correspondientes al usuario logueado porque no se me ocurre otra cosa, gracias por tu aportacion @Txema

Comment: vaya que paranoia, claro, si directamente sacas los datos de php que necesitas te quitas de problemas en el javascript, ademas de hacer mas liviana la carga. buena suerte, cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: No te preocupes, lo hare asi, digamos que queria intentarlo, pero si me va a dar dolores de cabeza, paso, muchas gracias por tu atencion :)